# Success{ } not getting executed in .ajax block

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to ***extract data from the XML file to the HTML page***.

The purpose here is to display the data onto the page.

The code below is directly executing the error block and able to end the execution but its not executing the success block, and its not giving any syntactic error as well.

I referred to the [.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as well in order to see if I am implementing something in an incorrect way , but still in vain.

The url might be an issue but its basically not taking any url whether the complete directory path or the one below.

Please suggest a solution to this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../assets/xml/blog.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    //data: (title, title),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(data).find('.item').each(function(){
         var title = $(this).find('.title').text();
     });
        $('.blog').append({
            text: title
        });      
    },
    error: function(data){
        $('.blog').text('No Blogs Found!');
    },
    //complete: function(data){
    //    $('.blog').text('All blogs are here!')
    //}
});
```

Comment: is there any error displaying in console?

Comment: the `data` in the error block should be enough information to see what the error is

Comment: Yes. It shows an error of 404 in the console.

Comment: _"Yes. It shows an error of 404 in the console."_ Try substituting full path to file location for `"../assets/xml/blog.xml"`

Comment: Tried that. It didn't work

Comment: i think its because of the location where the xml is placed. From which directory are you trying to access the xml.?
and remember to remove that coma(,) after the error function (its not actually needed)

Comment: The xml file is assets/xml folder. @AdarshMohan

Comment: then from where are you loading this script?

Comment: from a separate js folder under assets

Comment: then you dont have to specify the assets folder again.. simply make it to "../xml/blog.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Error could be at

```
$(data).find('.item').each(function(){
  var title = $(this).find('.title').text();
});

$('.blog').append({
  text: title
});
```

where `data` is `document` , not root element of `xml` document ; `title` not appear defined outside of `.each()` ; `.append()` expects a `String` or `Function` , not an object literal .

Try selecting `documentElement` from returned `data` using `.append()` within `.each()` with parameter `title` as string returned by `$(this).find('.title').text()`

```
$(data.documentElement).find('.item').each(function(){
  var title = $(this).find('.title').text();
   $('.blog').append(title);   
});
```

Comment: I tried your code snippet but still ..in vain.
Thanks anyways.  @guest271314

Comment: Yes. It shows "data
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", responseXML: null, status: 404, statusText: "error"}" in the console.

Comment: Does the file exist at the location of the fill path ? Tried with another file ?

Comment: The file exists. I did try with new file and also tried by changing the file location to root but it does seem to access the file, no matter wherever its located.

Comment: @AtulKumar Are any other files accessible with ajax that do not return `404` ?